# cancel all pending requests angular4

Tags: angular2-services, angular2-http

How can I cancel all pending promises in angular2. I know that promises are not cancellable, but is there some work around for this?How can I cancel all pending requests on logout.

api-service

```
get(url: string) {
        let that = this;
        let getPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this
                .httpService
                .get(url)
                // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(that.handleError(error));
                }, () => {
                    console.log('API Subscription Complete!');
                });
        });
        return getPromise;
    }
```

component-service

```
fetchData(url) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this
                .apiService
                .get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                }).catch(error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: It seems that the Promises cannot be canceled.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8525

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unsubscribe();` of observable

```
subscribeRequest.unsubscribe();
```

for more information please refer [This article](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/)

Comment: Yes but I am using promises :(

Comment: I am not sure about angular, but you can refer this for more information https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: you can defer a promise